# react-router: 'history' is missing in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

some code of App.tsx:

```
interface AppProps{
  history: any
}

export default class App extends React.Component<AppProps,...> {

  public state = {
    target: this.props.history.push('/')
  };

  private route() {
    if (!session.isLogin) {
        this.setState({ target: this.props.history.push('/') });
        return
    } else {
        this.setState({ target: this.props.history.push('/root') })
    }
  }
  ...
  public render() {
    return this.state.target
  }
}
```

some code of index.tsx

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MemoryRouter>
    <LocaleProvider locale={zhCn}>
        <App history={ ???? }/>
    </LocaleProvider>
  </MemoryRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Why is the type of "history" wrong? tips：Property 'history' is missing in type '{}'. What parameters should I pass in index.tsx?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your interface is correct? Shouldn't it be ```history?: any``` (optional)

Comment: But then it will prompt "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `App` to receive all of the `RouteComponentProps` (including the history object) from the `MemoryRouter`, then you need to call `App` via a route, something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MemoryRouter>
    <LocaleProvider locale={zhCn}>
        <Route component={App}/>
    </LocaleProvider>
  </MemoryRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

Then you can replace `AppProps` with `RouteComponentProps<{}>` in the declaration of `App`.